# Upgrading ruby 1.8->1.9 and Rails 2.3-3.0 - which should be first?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, upgrade

I'm in the unfortunate position of having inherited an app that is still running ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.

I'm trying to work out a migration plan. From what I have googled, rails 2.3 doesn't easily run on ruby 1.9, and it's hacky to get it to do so. So it would seem that it's better-advised to upgrade rails to 3.0 first, then upgrade to ruby 1.9.

Does anyone agree or disagree?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I agree that upgrading to Rails 3.x *first*, *then* upgrading to Ruby 1.9.x, is a good approach.  However, at this point, Rails 3.0 should *not* be your end goal - I recommend shooting for something in the 3.2.x family, or possibly even 4.

That said, here's a hard-won piece of advice; however you upgrade, be sure that you upgrade to Rails 3.1.x *before* you upgrade to 3.2.x or 4.  [As Patrik Naik hints at](http://m.onkey.org/active-record-query-interface), there are several constructs which were legal in 2.x, were deprecated in 3.0.x (or 3.1.x), and were then removed entirely in 3.2.x.  Those deprecation came with runtime warnings.

So,

- If you upgrade to Rails 3.1 and one of those outdated constructs accidentally survives the upgrade, the code will still run (either in tests or on live servers), injecting warnings into your logs.  You can then grep for those error in the logs and address them.
- If, on the other hand, you skip Rails 3.1 and go right to 3.2 (or 4), those outdated constructs *won't* run successfully, and will either take your app down or (worse) give incorrect results.  Been there, done that, it's not pretty.

Comment: Agree, do not stop at Rails 3.0. Also do not stop at Ruby 1.9, migration to 2.0 is quite straightforward.